# Suggestions for a GTK3 theme with round corners

Tags: themes, gtk3

I am looking for a modern GTK3 theme which has round corners like the image below:

[image: screenshot of ubuntu 10.04]

This image shows the old Ambiance theme used in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Later on, Ubuntu decided to remove these round corners at the bottom of the Ambiance theme while these corners can still be seen in original Apple OS X window theme.

My question is why did they decide to remove these round corners at the bottom?

I searched https://www.gnome-look.org but I was not able to find a modern theme.

Can you suggest me a modern GTK3 theme which has them?

Answer (score 0):

How about the theme **Mac OSX Yosemite**? I like it. However corner radius is less a little and there no gradients used.

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013741/

[image][image]

Comment: But the bottom corners are rounded, are they? I think OP pointed out that requirement in the screenshot.

Comment: @pomsky Uh sorry, I overlooked it. Will remove my answer.

Comment: I would ask you to keep it. OP and others still might find it useful.